# Forgot to use & after command, need to send process to background

Tags: command-line, nohup

I have been running a program using nohup but I forgot to add & after the command so the terminal is stuck on the process that has been running for hours. the script I am running in python generates 5 processes each time.

Is there anyway I can make the entire script to continue in the background (get the same effect as an &) without killing and rerunning the process.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Hit `Ctrl-Z` to suspend the process.

Then `bg` to tell it to run again as a background process.